# How get CentOs Source repository

Tags: centos, repository

I use reposyc to get {base,extra,update} centos repository but I can not download the sources repository.

my original CentOS-Sources.repo has this lines:

```
[base-source]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base Sources
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/Source/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

when I run below command

```
reposync --gpgcheck -l --repoid=base-source --download_path=/mnt/extra
```

It just print this lines:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * fasttrack: mirror.centos.jt.iq
```

even change my CentOS-Sources.repo to this:

```
[base-source]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base Sources
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.7.1908/updates/Source
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

and it does not work.

Comment: Try to clear `yum` cache and again to sync

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `--source` flag for `reposync` to also download `.src.rpm` files:

```
reposync --gpgcheck -l --repoid=base-source --download_path=/mnt/extra --source
```